# Creating/Deleteing Bulk Users to Active Directory Using a Script in Powershell

Tags: powershell

The guidelines are:

Script 1: Add/Remove Users
Fields: Username, FirstName, LastName, Description, OUPath, Password, Action (Add | Remove)

So far I have

```
$oulist = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AddUser.csv"
Foreach ($ou in $oulist)
{
New-ADOrganizationalUnit ` 
-Name $ou.Username `
-Firstname $ou.Firstanem `
-Lastname $ou.Lastname `
-Description $ou.Description `
-Path $ou.OUpath `
-Password $ou.Password `
-Action
```

I'm confused what to write under action. I need one to create the users based off the csv file and another to delete the users based of the csv file.

Comment: The Script should Add/Remove the User based off the Action field in the csv file

Comment: What you have here will create new Organizational Units, not users. Did you try finding a cmdlet that was for users? This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment, are you asking the internet to do your homework for you?

Comment: Ooops yeah so it would be New-ADUser, i'm asking the internet to help me with my homework

Comment: @Nitro, could you fix the question then if you found the error?

Answer (score 1):

1. To create new users, use [New-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
2. To delete, use [Remove-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Do actually read through the links, and check for the actual attribute names. For example, you have `FirstName` and `LastName`, but those attributes are set with `-GivenName` and `-Surname` instead. Using a visual editor like powershell's ISE or VS Code will help with this.